# How can I change the wording of the "In Honor of" tab?

Tags: contribution-page

How can I say "First Name of Person Being Honored/Memoralized," "Last Name of Person Being Honored/Memoralized," etc. in the contribution page instead of "First Name," Last Name," etc.

Comment: What version of Civi and what CMS (Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla) are you using?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the `.extra.tpl` method ([original blog post](https://civicrm.org/blogs/dave-greenberg/now-its-easier-add-custom-behaviors-templates), [forum post](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=20945.0) or [from the wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Page+Templates#PageTemplates-AppendingjQueryorothercodetoatemplate)) to add jQuery to the page.  To identify a potential starting point for which tpl file to use in front of `.extra.tpl`, right-click on your contribution page and View Source.  Then do a find (usually CRTL+F) for `tpl`.  The forum post suggests that a good starting point might be `CRM/Contribute/Page/Tab.extra.tpl`.

You would select your particular field labels and use a jQuery function like [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).